# Inbuilt browser on a JPanel

Tags: java, html, swing, browser, jtextpane

I'm trying to create a JPanel that displays webpages. I've gotten to the stage
where I can read the webpage, however when I display the page, it looks all muddled
up, see below.

[image]

Here is the source code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Browser {
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panelTop;
private JEditorPane editor;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private JTextField field;
private JButton button;
private URL url;

public Browser(String title) {
    initComponents();

    //set the title of the frame
    frame.setTitle(title);

    //set the default cloe op of the jframe
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //set size of frame
    frame.setSize(800,600);

    //add jpanel to north of jframe
    frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panelTop);

    //add textfield and navigation button to jpanel.
    panelTop.add(field);
    panelTop.add(button);

    //add scroll pane to jframe center
    frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scroll);


    //set the frame visible
    frame.setVisible(true);
}//end Browser() constructor

private void initComponents() {
    //create the JFrame
    frame = new JFrame();

    //create the JPanel used to hold the text field and button.
    panelTop = new JPanel();

    //set the url
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.google.co.uk");
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException mue) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mue);
    }

    //create the JEditorPane
    try {
        editor = new JEditorPane(url);

        //set the editor pane to false.
        editor.setEditable(false);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ioe);
    }

    //create the scroll pane and add the JEditorPane to it.
    scroll = new JScrollPane(editor, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    //create the JTextField
    field = new JTextField();

    //set the JTextField text to the url.
    //we're not doing this on the event dispatch thread, so we need to use
    //SwingUtilities.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           field.setText(url.toString());
       }
    });

    //create the button for chanign pages.
    button = new JButton("Go");

    //add action listener to the button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                editor.setPage(field.getText());
            }
            catch(IOException ioe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe);
            }
        }
    });
}//end initComponents()

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Browser("Simple web browser");
        }
    });
}//end main method.
}//end Browser class
```

Is there some methods I am missing that read CSS ande flash etc?

Comment: I'm almost certain that JEditorPane is not able to handle most modern web content types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because `JEditorPane` renders old (parts of 3.2) HTML and simple CSS does not make it a browser.  It is suitable only for content that you control.

> Is there some methods I am missing that read CSS ..

It does support simple styles.

> .. flash etc?

Not supported in the default [HTML editor kit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html).

Support for new HTML elements *can* be added to the editor kit, but you need to supply the component that renders the Flash, ..applet, whatever.

Comment: Is there an alternative that I can use?

Answer (score 4):

Well, yes. Normally whan you use some Java http client (in this case JEditorPane's ability to get Html response from an url) to get the response from the HTTP address, you'll get the text but without the execution of the Javascript code and also no RIA widgets output (such as Flash, Silverlight, etc). Now for the Javascript issue you can use HtmlUnit (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which does execute the Javascript, but you're still outta luck for the Flash widgets.

However the Google page you're trying to display here usually doesn't have any Flash or anything like that. Just use HTMLUnit to get the html (plus executed javascript) from the url, and display that. You might need to further manually parse that HTML in order to finetune your Swing GUI.

Lobo is an Open Source Java Web Browser. you might want to checkout its sources and see how those guys did it:

http://lobobrowser.org/sourcecode.jsp